# How can I check the extra logger content with caplog?

Tags: python, pytest

I made a unit test with mocker on a log:

Code:

```py
def my_func():
    extra = my_http_call(): # returns {"foo": "bar"}
    logger.warning(
       "My warning",
       extra=extra
    )
```

To test this I used mocker:

```py
def test_my_func(mocker):
    import logging
    mocker.patch("logging.Logger.warning")
    my_func()
    logging.Logger.warning.assert_called_once_with(
        "My warning",
        extra={"foo": "bar"}
    )
```

But to be harmonise with the other tests I would like to uses [caplog](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html). So my test became:

```
def test_my_func(caplog):
    my_func()
    assert caplog.messages == ["My warning"]
```

I search a way to test the content of `extra` data but I doesn't found nothing about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key-value pairs given in `extra` are "[... used to populate the __dict__ of the LogRecord created for the logging event with user-defined attributes."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug) You can then assert on these attributes by accessing the records captured by `caplog`:

```
def test_my_func(caplog)
    my_func()
    assert caplog.records[0].foo == "bar"
```